# finding the matrix and kernel of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $P_n$ denote the vector space of all polynomials in one variable with real coefficients and of degreeless than, or equal to,n, equipped with the standard basis {$1,x,x^2,…,x^n$}. Define $T:P_2→P_3$ by $T(p)(x)=∫_0^xp(t)dt+ p’(x)+p(2)$.
Write down the matrix of this transformation with respect to the standard bases of $P_2$ and $P_3$.
And determine the dimension of the kernel of the linear transformation $T$ defined above.

After a calculation I find that the matrix will be
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
3 & 0 & 1/2 & 0\\
4 & 2 & 0 & 1/3
\end{bmatrix}$$

and $\ker T =\{0\}$. Does my calculation alright.

Comment: Looks good to me.

Answer (score 4):

$$\begin{align*}T(1)&=\int\limits_0^x1\cdot dt+1'+1=x+1\\T(x)&=\int\limits_0^xt\,dt+1+2=\frac{1}{2}x^2+3\\T(x^2)&=\int\limits_0^xt^2\,dt+2x+4=\frac{1}{3}x^3+2x+4\end{align*}$$

The corresponding matrix is thus

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&3&4\\{}\\1&0&2\\{}\\0&\frac{1}{2}&0\\{}\\0&0&\frac{1}{3}\end{pmatrix}$$

which I think fits your answer but you seem to have interchanged rows and columns.This is right **if** you apply matrices (and functions) *from the right*, something almost nobody does in these days. If you people apply matrices and functions from the left then your matrix **must** be $\,4\times 3\,$